# How do I handle encoding Korean in swift with alamofire?

Tags: swift, xcode, encoding, utf-8, alamofire

I am getting Korean data from the api server through alamofire. However, the data I receive breaks as below.

ëë¶ìë°©ì

where in the middle it should be korean but returns unrecognizable symbols. How do I encode this data to be korean again?

this is the code I use in alamofire

```
Alamofire.request(BusURL + "?\(urlParams)", method: .get).validate()
        .responseString {}
```

Comment: Seems like the response string is encoded in another encoding. Try finding out which encoding the server uses.

Comment: The string interpolation (`"?\(urlParams)"`) may be the source of the error. Have you tried building your URL with [`URLComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents)?